# Scraping TripAdvisor search query results

Tags: rvest, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to scrape the number of times a particular search term (in this case "sunset") is referenced in TripAdvisor reviews at different sights/locations, but I'm getting a http 403 error.

Is there a fix, of is this TripAdvisor not wanting me to scrape this page?

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
install.packages("xml2")
library(xml2)

place <- xml2::read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Search?q=sunset&geo=186216") %>%
html_nodes(".result-title") %>%
html_text()
place

sunsets <- xml2::read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Search?q=sunset&geo=186216") %>%
html_nodes(".review-mention-block") %>%
html_text()
sunsets
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding an user-agent header via httr?

Comment: Why would I need to set a user-agent rather than using the default?

Comment: And yes, I gave it a go after your suggestion, but still getting the 403 error.